# FTP ls command returned a empty list

Tags: ftp

When I used the `ls` command, it returns an empty list to me, just like this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ftp 127.0.0.1
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
220 欢迎使用 Quick 'n Easy FTP Server
User (127.0.0.1:(none)): admin
331 admin 需要密码
Password:
230 用户已成功登录。
ftp> ls
200 Port 命令成功。
226 传输完成
ftp>
```

I made sure that the folder isn't empty and all firewalls are turned off.

Comment: You can, at least, verify (possible) permission and ownership problem - files exist, but with "these" owner and permissions (no 'r' totally) they way invisible. Check also server-logs for possible unrelated errors and current folder for x permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try to 'put' a file there, and see if `ls / dir` then sees it.